# Where does Ubuntu 10.04 store the configuration file of mod-security?

Tags: ubuntu, mod-security

I've installed libapache-mod-security on Ubuntu 10.04. The only configuration file I've been able to find is this one:

```
# cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/libapache-mod-security.conffiles
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mod-security.load
```

However, this does not match the configuration file mentioned in the mod_security documentation. It only tells Apache in which directory to find the module. Where are the mod-security rules stored?

Comment: Here's a HOWTO for 9.04, I suspect it's valid for 10.04 too. Let me know if it helps http://acidborg.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/installing-modsecurity-for-apache-in-ubuntu-server-9-04/

Comment: Hi Richard! Thanks, but that blogpost is missing some images supposedly containing XML code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try /etc/apache2/conf.d/modsecurity2.conf ?

-edit-

This apparently applies to all versions of Ubuntu: [mod_security](http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/how-to-mod_security-ubuntu-904/)

Comment: This file does not exist by default, but it looks like this is the recommended location and filename to use.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is well known to change configuration file without any reason (they did alot with apache).

So try to search the internet for apache conf file in unbuntu or try the locate command (with proper file name) and you'll  maybe find what you're searching for.

Answer (score 0):

You may try following command.

```
apt-cache show libapache2-mod-security2
```

It works on Ubuntu 18, not sure about Ubuntu 10.04